# Why use <div class="container"> just below the body element in HTML instead of putting it in body element directly?

Tags: html, css, containers

Should I use
 `<body> ,  <div class="container">  or <body class="container">`

Is there some instance of CSS I can write that makes one preferable over the other?

I tried these

```
 .container {
        width: 80vw;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 3vh;
    }

    body {
        width: 80vw;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 3vh;
    }
```

but the result was the same

Comment: You might have a body > header, body > main, body > footer. In this case, you'd probably put .container on main. You can basically structure your html/css any way you want to & there will be benefits & trade-offs to whatever you come up with. Personally, I prefer specificity, like I'd use 'body.container' or 'body > div.container' to prevent conflicts with other nodes that use the container class. But that specificity also introduces its own difficulties, where you might need an !important to override bc body > div.container is so specific.

Comment: As far as which you should use in your specific case - that's highly subjective. I would prefer to put minimal styling on the body tag itself, because it's easier to make changes if the bulk of styling is on a child. But decisions like these are often subtle and learned through experience, IMO.

Comment: There are an infinite number of reasons why you would want to have a `div` directly within your `body`, from aesthetic to semantic. Please limit your question to some kind of limiting factor as right now it is asking for an infinite list.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with styling the `<body>` directly per se. However one reason I can think of styling a `<div>` instead of the `<body>` is if you plan on swapping out the container `<div>` with another [differently] styled `<div>` with JavaScript. There are no absolute right or wrong ways to use CSS, only "more right" and "more wrong" ways, and in this specific situation it's just preference.

For example, inline CSS versus CSS located in stylesheets debate...there are many situations where it's recommended to use inline CSS instead of putting it in a stylesheet (such as when an element needs an extremely specific style that will only exist in one place in your application). Do what is most scalable and understandable for you now and you will learn along the way why people do what they do with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you *can't* add classes to the `body`, but generally you don't see this because documents will only every have one `body` element, so styles are usually applied directly to `body` rather than a class applied to `body`.

In the case of a [bootstrap `container`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/), if you make the body a container, you won't be able to easily create elements that extend the full width of the page, and you'd have to use negative width, positioning changes, or other stylings to get the element to extend past it's parent.

```css
.container {
  padding: 0 10vw;
}
```

```html
<body class="container">
  <div style="background-color: red">
    This div can't fill the body here without more styles
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: lime; margin: 0 -10vw">
    This div can, using negative margin
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 0 10vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container" style="background-color: red">
      By moving the class to a div inside the body, we can have elements stretch the page without resorting to negative margin.
  </div>
</body>
```